# Filter all nodes in returned path for criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all nodes connecting `start` with `end` via `EDGE`. However, of those I only want to know the nodes that have the label `END` or that are part of a subgraph where a `CERTAIN_EDGE` is involved.

The below query returns way to many nodes and the result does not make sense as it is the same number for each count.

```
MATCH p = (start)-[:EDGE*0..]->
          (between)->[:EDGE*0..]->
          (end:END)
WHERE id(start) = {start_id} AND
        (between)-[:OTHER_EDGE*]->()-[:CERTAIN_EDGE]->()
RETURN start, between, end
```

Intuitively I would apply a `FOREACH` in the return only collecting the nodes I am interested in, but it seems that `FOREACH` [cannot collect](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/) stuff.

Comment: Try using `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` instead of `COUNT(x)`.

Comment: I do not necessarily want the count, I want the nodes. However, my POC returned quite a bit of nodes. This is the reason why I only return the count. As the counts are the !same! the `DISTINCT` should not make a difference

Comment: To the contrary, `DISTINCT` will very probably cause different counts for your query. Right now, you are in effect just counting (in 3 different ways) the number of rows generated by the `MATCH` clause -- so the counts must be identical.  Also, if you have other queries to fix, please show them in your question.

Comment: that was the query, I changed the query to its version without `COUNT` now. But the query returns way too many nodes to display (and work with). I.e., my own answer returns 7 nodes on my test set whereas the above query returns 32k

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER` is the `FOREACH` of returns

```
MATCH path = (start)-[:EDGE*0..]->
             (end:END)
WHERE id(start) = {start_id}
RETURN DISTINCT filter( node in nodes(path) 
                        WHERE (node)-[:OTHER_EDGE*]->
                              ()-[:CERTAIN_EDGE]->() ),
       end
```